# jquery - click event breaks parallax

Tags: jquery

I have this click event like so:

```
$('.architectural-films').bind('click', function(e){
     $(".section1").toggleClass("toggle");
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

I also have a parallax before and after the class architectural-films, before I click the button both parallax work, after I click the button the parallax below the class architectural-films is broken and no longer parallax anymore. The parallax above the class architectural-films is still working after I click the button. Is there something wrong with my click event?

Here is my CSS code.

```
.section1 {
    max-height: 0px;
    transition: max-height 1.00s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.toggle{
    max-height: 5000px;
    transition: max-height 1.30s ease-in;
}
```

Here is the HTML for the parallax

```
   <div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" data-vc-stretch-content="true" data-vc-parallax="1.5" data-vc-parallax-o-fade="on" data-vc-parallax-image="http://new.sekanskin.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/windows-walls-floors.jpg" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid what-we-do-service vc_row-has-fill vc_row-no-padding vc_general vc_parallax vc_parallax-content-moving-fade js-vc_parallax-o-fade" style="position: relative; left: -405px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 1940px;">
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12 skrollable skrollable-after" data-5p-top-bottom="opacity:0;" data-30p-top-bottom="opacity:1;" style="opacity: 0;">
            <div class="vc_column-inner">

                <div class="wpb_wrapper"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_parallax-inner skrollable skrollable-after" data-bottom-top="top: -50%;" data-top-bottom="top: 0%;" style="height: 150%; background-image: url(&quot;http://new.sekanskin.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/windows-walls-floors.jpg&quot;); top: 0%;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think e.preventDefault(); should be first  instruction

Comment: I made that change, didn't work :(

Comment: ok...can you post also the html?

Comment: It looks everything ok. I tried your website and it works fine on chrome....tried to clear cache?

Comment: @Kurohige I cleared my cache, even tried another browser, the parallax scrolling is still not working.